# Sending multiple type of data from a single network stream in C#

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I am creating a program similar to Microsoft Netmeeting for that I have to send Multiple type of data from a single connection such as Mouse position, Pressed key and offcourse a screen shot at a time. I am success fully sending and receiving Screen shot to the client but I am unable to understand how multiple data could be send through the single connetion.

I think it require multiple ports for this purpose. One for Screen shot, One for Mouse Pos and One for Key pressed.

Following are the codes I am using:
Server = Sender of ScreenShot, Recever of MousePos and Key.
Client = Receiver of ScreenShot, Sender of MousePos and Key.

Server:

```
void StartListen()
{
    try
    {
        IPEndPoint ipendp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(OwnIP()), 532);
        tcpl = new TcpListener(ipendp);
        tcpl.Start();
        s1 = tcpl.AcceptSocket();
        ns = new NetworkStream(s1);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buffer = imageToByteArray(CaptureScreenShot());
            s1.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        tcpl.Stop();
        ns.Close();
        //tcpl.EndAcceptSocket();
        Form1_Load(0,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
void StartClient()
{
    try
    {

        IPEndPoint ipendp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(toolStripTextBox1.Text), 532);
        this.Text = "SWare Application - " + toolStripTextBox1.Text + ":532";
        tcpc = new TcpClient();
        tcpc.Connect(ipendp);
        Socket s1 = tcpc.Client;
        ns = tcpc.GetStream();

        while (true)
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[500000];
            s1.Receive(b);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            //Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        tcpc.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Disconnected from the Remote PC");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single connection, but you have to provide a way for the receiver to differentiate the type of data (and its size) prior to reading it.

That being said, if you're writing both sides of the connection (the client + server), it would be far simpler to use a technology like WCF.  It would allow you to pass full class instances with strongly typed data, and take care of the underlying transport (in a configurable way) for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** You could use a header in your stream. On the receiving side you read the header and switch accordingly.

With a simple one byte header this might be something along the lines of...

### Sender for type 'a':

```
using (MemoryStream mems = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Store data in MemoryStream
    // It's searchable which may be required
    // ...
    using (TcpClient tcp = newTcpClient())
    {
        using (NetworkStream ns = tcp.GetStream())
        {
            ns.WriteByte((int)'a'); // Store data type header for type 'a'
            mems.WriteTo(ns); // Write serialized data to network
        }
    }
}
```

### Receiver:

```
void receiveData(NetworkStream ns)
{
    using (MemoryStream mems = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int formatByte = ns.ReadByte(); // Read the data type header

        ns.CopyTo(mems);
        mems.Position = 0;

        switch (formatByte)
        {
            case (int)'a': // Type A
                // Read type 'a' from "mems"
                // ...
                break;

            case (int)'b': // Type B
                // Read type 'b' from "mems"
                // ...
                break;

            default:
                // In case you want to point out the unrecognized type
                break;
        }
    }
}
```